# Механизм вывода информации из бд

Tags: php, база-данных, вёрстка, вывод

у меня широкий вопрос цель которого узнать механизм реализации. При обычной верстки я могу размещать информацию так, как мне нужно с помощью стилей css. А как реализовать вывод всей информации из бд не в столбик. Самое легкое что можно сделать это выводить через id каждый элемент из бд в определенный div и таким образом размещать информацию так, как мне нужно. А при выводе всех столбцов появляется проблема. Буду благодарен за ответ, так же подойдет простенький пример с демонстрацией воплощения. Понимаю что для людей связанных с php и бд это глупый вопрос, но он ставит меня в тупик. На скриншоте указан вид вывода на данный момент, с точки зрения дизайна это ужасно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _механизм реализации_ он всегда один - берём с базы, выводим на страницу.. Приведите пример данных, и того, что не получается

Comment: сделайте ваши дивы inline-block, будет все так же ужасно, но чуточку лучше

Comment: Насколько я помню инлайн даст расположение в строку, так еще хуже. Объясните как возможно задать нормальный вывод или как это делаете вы

Comment: @Сергей    код в студию. За вас здесь его писать никто не будет, подсказать на уже сделанные вами попытки - да.